# how to get specific value from json object which contains json array in angularjs

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

i get the following data from mysql data base where "comment" is from one table  and "blog" is another table .  now i want to show this data in view through ng-repeat.

```
{
  "comment":[
    {"comment_id":"3","blog_id":"1","total_comment":"2"},
    {"comment_id":"9","blog_id":"8","total_comment":"3"}
  ],
  "blog":[
    {"id":"9","title":"jquery","description":"this is about jquery","date":"2016-08-27","status":"active"},
    {"id":"8","title":"javascript","description":"this is javascript post","date":"0000-00-00","status":"active"},
    {"id":"1","title":"angularjs","description":"this blog is about angularjs.this blog is about angularjs.this blog is about angularjs.this blog is about angularjs.this blog is about angularjs.this blog is about angularjs.","date":"2016-07-12","status":"active"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried??

Comment: <div ng-repeat="result in data"> {{result.comment.total_comment}} and {{result.blog.title}} </div>

Comment: i have already get the data in response now how to access specific record which i needed

Answer (score 0):

If believe "blog_id" is the common field between the blog table and the comment table.

Write a Join query in mysql "ON blog.id = comment.blog_id" so that you get the data you wanted and you may display the response in ng-repeat